# Can Google Oauth redirect_uri be configured with pattern?

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid

I have a hosted application that runs in own domain (customer.appdomain.com). Google SSO was enabled with OpenID but it is scheduled to discontinued. I plan to migrate to Oauth2 but would like to know the best way to manage redirect_uri configuration.

Can I use a pattern *.appdomain.com ?

This is essential as subdomain addition / deletion are random.

Hoping to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you cannot. What you can do is use one single domain to authenticate your users (such as auth.appdomain.com) and then use some SSO system (shared cookie on *.appdomain.com for example) to transmit the user id to the *.appdomain.com domains.

Comment: You can also specify multiple redirect_uri's. This is quite common eg. for testing domains, http and https, etc. You can also follow David's suggestion and make use of the "scope" parameter for your onward routing.